# How do I POST raw data in Dyalog APL HttpCommand?

Tags: http, post, apl, dyalog

I am trying to submit data as plain text using HttpCommand object. I know how to do it with cURL, but I'm unsure how to specify the data in my HttpCommand object. Here's how I would do it with cURL:

```bash
curl -request POST "http://my-api-url" --header "Content-Type: text/plain" --data-raw "here is my test"
```

What's the equivalent way to send the plain text data in my HttpCommand object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most direct analogous HttpCommand equivalent is:

```
      r←HttpCommand.Do 'post' 'http://my-api-url' 'here is my test' ('content-type' 'text/plain')
```

The basic syntax for `HttpCommand.Do` is:

```
      r←HttpCommand.Do 'Command' 'URL' Params Headers
```

- `Command` is the HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, etc)
- `URL` is the URL
- `Params` the data for the request. If the `Command` is `'GET'`, HttpCommand will URLEncode `Params` and include it as the query string of the request. Otherwise, it will be send as the payload (body) of the request.
- `Headers` is a set of 0 or more name/value pairs to be used as the HTTP headers for the request. It can be any of:

  - a 2-column matrix - `(2 2⍴'content-type' 'text/plain' 'accept' 'text/html')`
  - a vector of 2-element vectors of strings - `(('content-type' 'text/plain')('accept' 'text/html'))`
  - a vector with an even number of strings - `('content-type' 'text/plain' 'accept' 'text/html')`

`r` will be a namespace containing information about the response.
`r.rc` is the return code where 0 indicates your request was successfully sent and a response receieved.
`r.HttpStatus` is the HTTP status code. A 2XX status means that the request was successful.
`r.Data` is the response payload (body), if any was sent by the server.
`r.Headers` is a 2-column matrix of the response's HTTP header name/value pairs.
`r` contains other elements as well.

There are other ways to accomplish the same task using HttpCommand that may be useful - for instance if you want to issue multiple requests to the same host.

These are all covered in the [HttpCommand documentation](https://dyalog.github.io/HttpCommand/5.1/)